# How much space do I need for a Fedora 23 Gnome installation (in slash root)

Tags: fedora

How much space do I need in / (slash root) for a typical Fedora 23 Gnome installation? 
Not planning to install any large packages like Games, Texlive, JDK, ADK or so.

Thanks.

Comment: I started using 20 GB drives for my virtual machines, but around 10 should fit basic needs.

Answer (score 1):

From [Official Fedora Documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Welcome_to_Fedora_.html#sect-Release_Notes-Overview):

> Minimum System Configuration The figures below are a recommended
> minimum for the default installation. Your requirements may differ,
> and most applications will benefit from more than the minimum
> resources.
>
> - 1GHz or faster processor
> - 1GB System Memory
> - 10GB unallocated drive space

Comment: So 10 GB is enough? Since disk space is only medium-expensive (SSD), I don't want to waste space but also make sure that I have at least 20 % free at all times.

Comment: Yes, this is without a /swap. Fedora 23 takes something around 4-5 Gb, this means you will have 4-6 Gb free space. I can't give you specific number, but 10 GB are enough to install most of the Linux distros with GUI.